# Duplicate ids are coming into result with some null values

Tags: bash, jq, couchbase

I have the below JSON where I want to filter out unique product.id into the array variable.

I am using the below query but the result is not coming in the proper way.

`productIds=($(jq -r .items[].product.id $Outputfile))`

**Actual output**:
123
123
123
456
456
null
null

**Expected output**:
123
456

```json
{
  "documentType": "product",
  "items": [
    {
      "ResourceId": null,
      "product": {
        "href": null,
        "id": "123",
        "mainId": "qwe345",
        "primaryId": "5298"
      },
      "lastModifiedBy": "test",
      "quantity": null,
      "effectiveDate": null,
      "extensions": null
    },
    {
      "product": {
        "href": null,
        "id": "123",
        "mainId": "qwe678",
        "primaryId": "5643"
      },
      "lastModifiedBy": "test",
      "quantity": null,
      "effectiveDate": null,
      "extensions": null
    }
  ],
  "createdBy": "test",
  "createdOn": "2021-10-05",
  "currentSeqNum": 2
}
```

Then I want to encode those value into base64 format and then concatenate with some constant value. I am not able to concatenate with constant as well and store in same variable inside loop.

Can you please help me with above two issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `unique` after applying array conversion and then `join` such as

```
productIds=$(jq -r '[.items[].product.id] | unique | join(" ")' $Outputfile)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/XMhdjKbdI4)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. It worked.

Comment: Better with `readarray -t productIds < <(jq -r '[.items[].product.id] | unique[]' $Outputfile)`

Comment: thank you @LéaGris for the suggestion but it always brings the first match only

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan check again the array content `declare -p productIds` if you want to figure the entire array content. Your json sample indeed contains only two identical product ID `product.id="123"`. So once it is deduped, the array will contain only one record.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan see; https://jqplay.org/s/K23oGW-m58

Comment: yes I see the content on my OS as `declare -a productIds='([0]="1234" [1]="12345")'`  after tweaking the JSON for id values but `echo $productIds` returns `1234` after applying `readarray -t productIds < <(jq -r '[.items[].product.id] | unique[]' file.json)`. Btw the demo you have provide gives result expanded to two lines.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan See documentation how to print bash arrays. Like if you want it in one line: `printf '%s\n' "${productIds[*]}"`. If you want to iterate the Ids in a for loop: `for id in "${productIds[@]}"; do printf 'Example processing product Id: %s\n' "$id"; done`